# what does いて mean in ここにいても

Tags: words, conjugations, word-usage, grammar

hi im doing subs2srs decks and im going through the cards looking at grammer and i found this card that says ここにいてもでくることはなさそうだな and i dont understand how いて works.

Comment: `でくること` -- You meant to type で**き**ること, no?

Comment: This is one of the most common verbs いる, and it is conjugated using very basic grammar. Perhaps it would make more sense to start by getting a grasp of the basics, and then go on learning phrases from TV shows?

Answer (score 1):

いて is the て form of いる.

いる→いて
.